# Can and should I try enabling the CONFIG_INOTIFY kernel configuration option?

Tags: 11.04, kernel, laptop, powertop

PowerTOP just offered the following suggestion:

> Suggestion: Enable the CONFIG_INOTIFY
>   kernel configuration option. This
>   option allows programs to wait for
>   changes in files and directories
>   instead of having to poll for these
>   changes

It it worth pursuing this? How would I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have a recent kernel? PowerTOP is checking for an older option that was renamed to CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER, see [this bug report](http://www.mail-archive.com/power@bughost.org/msg01796.html). Of course, you should make sure that your kernel has CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER enabled -- if you have a stock kernel you should be fine. If you built your own and are using `make menuconfig` then look under Filesystems->Inotify Support for Userspace and make sure that is checked.

Answer (score 3):

CONFIG_INOTIFY is an option you can enable when building a Kernel - it is not an option you can manually enable via (for example) a grub boot option.

Some of the more recent kernels are built with CONFIG_INOTIFY=y - for example, in Maverick.

To see if your particular version of Ubuntu has its kernels built with this option, look [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/configs/) for your distribution & kernel type.  Then search for CONFIG_INOTIFY.